# I need some help about indexing a JSONB column

Tags: postgresql, index, postgresql-9.6, json

I'm a newbie with PostgreSQL and databases in general. I have PostgreSQL version 9.6.8 and in it there's a schema with JSON data in it.

Some of the fields are being indexed already, but there's a function that selects the data from all 10 of them. The index is this:

```
    ON "JSON".DATA USING btree
    ((data -> 'field1'::text), (data -> 'field2'::text))
    TABLESPACE pg_default;
```

If I index all the 10 fields will the select process be faster? From what i know about indexing and databases I assume it should be faster, but I need confirmation.

If indexing all the fields won't help can anyone give me any suggestion what would help make this faster?

The query is

```
SELECT id, data->>'field1', data->>'field2', data->>'field3', data->>'field4', 
 data->>'field5', data->>'field6', data->>'field7', data->>'field8', data->>'field9', 
data->>'field10', meta, checksum FROM JSON.DATA;
```

The column is created as `jsonb` with:

`ALTER TABLE "JSON".DATA ADD COLUMN data jsonb NOT NULL;`

Comment: An index is used to _find_ rows in a table. Your query has no `where` clause and thus it will never make use of an index.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name ok, thanks. just to clarify that's not my query :) someone did it some time ago. I'm just the new guy they're asking to make it work faster. I'll ask around if we can't do more accurate search using some where clause and index the columns with that data.

Comment: You can't really make that query faster - it reads all rows from the table - that's the bottleneck. An index won't be used to find all rows because there is nothing to find. The only way to make queries like that faster, is to get faster hardware

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name well that's AWS hosted RDS so i'll suggest that too.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name do you think partitioning would help in any way in this case? that was one of the things they told me to check, but i'm not sure how would that be of any use considering the data they add is on a daily basis and the used data is moved to another schema after it's used once.

Comment: If anything partitioning would make it slower as you have no where clause that would allow to remove partitions during the table scan